# Jquery duo checkbox, yes no, no yes, no no, how to deselect again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

How to return checkbox back to unselected on click? The two checkbox options should be, "yes, no" "no, yes" or "no, no" but once checkbox has been selected, i can flip between buy and sell (correct), but how to deselect the one selected again upon clicking, back to both unselected?

```
$('input.checkboxClass').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.checkboxClass').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true)
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yfmzorjp/)

Comment: From your DEMO, I would say that it makes no sense to use checkboxes. This is the case for radio buttons. [W3Schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio)

Comment: Please read the question again, radio buttons make no sense as i need to return back to "no no" state. If person selects product 2 buy, then decides against, you cannot unselect a radio button, so checkboxes please.

Comment: @dandanwell You can unselect a radio button using reset. Check out my answer.

Comment: Thanks Praveen, thats a great suggestion, its appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of all these, convert the checkboxes to radio buttons and group them using a name! And for deselecting, you can just give a reset.

```html
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Product 1 </td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Product1" class="checkboxClass" />Buy</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Product1" class="checkboxClass" />Sell</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product 2 </td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Product2" class="checkboxClass" />Buy</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Product2" class="checkboxClass" />Sell</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product 3 </td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Product3" class="checkboxClass" />Buy</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Product3" class="checkboxClass" />Sell</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><input type="reset" value="Clear All" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

No JavaScript or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

just set the checkbox of your "sibling" `<td>` to false, not all checkboxes of your `<tr>`:

```
$('input.checkboxClass').on('click', function(e) {
   $(this).parent().siblings().find('.checkboxClass').prop('checked', false);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/northkildonan/yfmzorjp/1/)

Comment: Wow, you got it northkildonan. This is the answer. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @dandanwell if it is the answer, then you should accept it by ticking the check mark below the voting arrows.

Answer (score 0):

I think Praveen's answer is the most correct one, but if you still need to do it with JS, I propose this way (check the status of the checkbox before performing an action):

```js
$('input.checkboxClass').on('click', function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.checkboxClass').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true)
  }
  else {
    $(this).prop('checked', false)
  }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfmzorjp/2/)

Comment: well, maybe look at my javascript solution. it's a little bit shorter :)